# jni: c to java char* buffer data passing in a generic format

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

We have a legacy C api that connects to a provider and gets market data at approx 100msgs/sec. All these messages are returned as (char*, headerSize) format. From that point onwards we do a lot of sizeof's etc to map that char* data into C Structures. Then we map these C structures onto Java classes via JNI.

So my question is that if we just return char* data to Java is there a way for us to extract the relevant information out into relevant classes given that Java does not support direct memory manipulations?

Do we have any other options apart from JNI that could possibly make our lives easier given that the provider changes the msg specs quite frequently.

Many Thanks,

Comment: You can't return `char*` to Java. You need to get the data into the JVM's heap for Java to be able to use it. What's the issue, exactly?

Comment: @rustyx I am basically trying to find a generic way to pass data(in different format) from C to Java where the data is all encapsulated in a C char* and I need to convert it into Java objects.

Comment: You can copy the data into a `byte[]` and return them to Java that way, so as to carve them up on the Java side.  If you don't want to have to use native methods to access and manipulate the data then that's your most generic alternative.